# Wifi adapter not found Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, wireless, msi

I have a problem with my wifi adapter after system update on Ubuntu 22.04.1.
Error is: "No wifi adapter found"

My system:

Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. GF63 Thin 11UD

Network controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 11)

Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

Result of "inxi -N" command:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi 
driver: iwlwifi

  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
driver: r8168
```

Comment: Have you find a solution to this @Herman ? facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue "No WiFi Adapter Found" and it persisted across restarting the computer. Saw [this thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/qe4njn/xps_15_9510_wifi_suddenly_stop_working_with_linux/) and tried power cycling my router then restarting. This worked...

I don't know how my main router caused my entire WiFi Adapter to not be found (I couldn't even see the area where I would normally see all nearby Wireless Networks). But very glad this worked.